# TypeError: Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, safemath

i have created a token ....but it gives me error
" erc20.sol:94:25: TypeError: Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256. balances[account] = balances[account].add(amount); ^-------------------^"

here is the code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe Math Library
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); c = a - b; } function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); } function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


contract MONK is IBEP20, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() public {
        name = "MY";
        symbol = "My";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 1000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(amount != 0);
    balances[account] = balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
  }

  function burn(uint256 amount) external {
    _burn(msg.sender, amount);
  }

  function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(amount != 0);
    require(amount <= balances[account]);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
    balances[account] = balances[account].sub(amount);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
  }

  function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) external {
    require(amount <= allowed[account][msg.sender]);
    allowed[account][msg.sender] = allowed[account][msg.sender].sub(amount);
    _burn(account, amount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `.add()` on line 94 is not defined anywhere.

You'll have other errors for `.sub()` on lines 106 and 112.

You have included `safeAdd()` and `safeSub()`, so you will need to use those.

**Edit:**

Your safe maths functions have no return statements.

**Edit#2:**

For the sake of time, this compiles:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe Math Library
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return a / b;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}


contract MONK is IBEP20, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() public {
        name = "MY";
        symbol = "My";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 1000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = sub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = add(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = sub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = sub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = add(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
      require(amount != 0);
      balances[account] = add(balances[account], amount);
      emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

  function burn(uint256 amount) external {
    _burn(msg.sender, amount);
  }

  function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(amount != 0);
    require(amount <= balances[account]);
    _totalSupply = sub(_totalSupply, amount);
    balances[account] = sub(balances[account], amount);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
  }

  function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) external {
    require(amount <= allowed[account][msg.sender]);
    allowed[account][msg.sender] = sub(allowed[account][msg.sender], amount);
    _burn(account, amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: i did same error

Comment: Have you changed the arguments as well? `.add()` is a method that takes one parameter, whereas `safeAdd()` is a function that takes two parameters...

Comment: i am new... can you please... show me how to do it?

Comment: I've edited my answer and changed the code so it compiles. Please have a read and understand the changes.

Comment: why mint is not showing?

Comment: Verify contract on BSCscan: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI